# $n$ is a positive integer and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n^{54}+n^{27}+1$. Prove if $p \ne 3$ then $ord_p(n) = 81$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod {81}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

more exam practice questions.

I feel like I am making some pretty futile attempts here and would greatly appreciate some insight and help!

Here is what I have so far:

First of all I think the question may be worded wrong, because it doesn't appear to hold that $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for any $n$.

So I just consider $p > 3$, Since $p |n^{54}+n^{27}+1$

$$ \implies n^{54}+n^{27} \equiv -1 \pmod p$$ Squaring both sides, and using Fermat's theorem yields:

$$ n^{p-1} \equiv n^{108}+2n^{81}+n^{54} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

Now I know that ultimately I want to show that $n^{81} \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$, and $81$ is the least integer such that this is so, and that $p-1=81k$. I also know that $ord_p(n) = j | p-1$, but I'm just not sure how to proceed from here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

$$n^{54}+n^{27}+1\equiv 0\pmod p\implies (n^{27}-1)(n^{54}+n^{27}+1)\equiv 0\implies n^{81}-1\equiv0\pmod p$$

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213361/showing-mathrmord-da-mid-mathrmord-ma-if-d-mid-m/213456#213456), ord_$\displaystyle_pn|81$

Now, if ord_$\displaystyle _pn|27, n^{27}\equiv1,n^{54}\equiv1\pmod p\implies n^{54}+n^{27}+1\equiv 3\pmod p$

But $\displaystyle n^{54}+n^{27}+1\equiv 0\pmod p\implies 3\equiv0\mod p\implies 3|p$

So, if $3\not|p, $   ord_$\displaystyle _pn\not|27$

Answer (score 1):

Observe $54=2\cdot27$ so $n^{54}+n^{27}+1=\displaystyle x^2+x+1=\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}$ where $x=n^{27}$.

Argue that $x\not\equiv1$ (via $p\ne 3$), so $x-1$ is a unit mod $p$. Now what is the order of $x$ mod $p$?

Comment: Thanks anon. Following your directions I need to show that $n^{27} \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$, since $p \ne 3$, but I don't see why this would be the case? Also, I do see that $n^{27 \cdot 3} \equiv 1$, but how can I be sure that this is the order?

Comment: @mathstudent If $x\equiv1$ then what is $x^2+x+1$ mod $p$? Now $n^{27\cdot3}\equiv1$ but $n^{27}\not\equiv1$ so the order of $n$ must divide $27\cdot3$ but cannot divide $27$. So what must the order of $n$ be?

Comment: ahh, I understand now. The only thing I would like to clear up is what is meant by - $x-1$ is a unit mod $p$? I'm guessing that it's just $1$ in mod p? And how does that follow from $x \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$? The fraction kind of confuses me, but besides that I do follow your solution. Many thanks!

Comment: @mathstudent If $x\not\equiv1$ then $x-1$ is invertible mod $p$ (that's what "unit" means). The fraction is just the geometric sum formula, which makes sense because $x-1$ is invertible.